# Estimating number of values between a range spanning several classes in a histogram

Tags: statistics

I have been struggling with this topic for ages, and my exam is on Wednesday. I understand how to construct and read a histogram, but I cannot wrap my head around questions where you are asked to find the number of objects within a range that differs from the class widths in the question.

For example, the table might be as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
Class & \text{Frequency} \\
\hline
4 - 6 & 6 \\
7 - 8 & 12 \\
9 & 21 \\
10 - 12 & 45 \\
13 - 15 & 9 \\
16 - 20 & 5 \\
\end{array}
$$

The question given is to estimate the number of values between 8.5 and 13.5. I'm not looking for a solution to the problem, I just need to understand how to answer it. I've tried looking for an explanation, but what I came across only explained how to draw the histogram.

Comment: sorry about the table, I don't know how to format it

Comment: nobody wants to read question like this - you should learn how to format a table in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and then ask the question again .. not trying to be mean just saying its way more likely that someone will answer if u format it nicely

Comment: @terrace I don't know how though, I spent ages trying to figure it out

Comment: [read this please](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5044/181915)

Comment: @terrace fixed it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: good job $\,$ +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data must be integers. (Otherwise, bins would
be labeled something like $[4, 8)$, $[7, 9),$ and so on.
So between 8.5 and 13.5, the integers are 9, 10, 11, 12, and 13.
The total frequency must be $21 + 45.$

A trickier problem would be to *estimate* the number of values
between 11 and 14 (inclusive), that is $[11, 14].$ It would be impossible to say for sure,
but the answer may be something like $(2/3)45 + (2/3)9,$ assuming
that interval $[10, 12]$ has three equally frequent values, and
similarly for $[13,15].$

*Notes:* (a) I am using standard interval notation, in which square brackets
include the endpoint and parentheses don't.
(b) It is common practice for histogram intervals to be of equal width.
In your histogram, I wonder why there is a separate interval that includes
only 9. Intervals of unequal width are sometimes used, but the purpose
of a histogram is to convey information clearly, and people are often
confused when intervals are of unequal width.

Comment: The reason why it's of unequal width because it's a past exam question